# Why we need to pass the InterfaceFactory to get the object rather than just pass the specific object

Tags: java, factory-pattern

There is one example of `Interface and Factories` in "Thinking In Java" as follows:

(1) Define the Game and GameFactory Interface

```
interface Game { boolean move(); }
interface GameFactory { Game getGame(); }
```

(2) Write their implementation

```
class Checkers implements Game {
     private int moves = 0;
     private static final int MOVES = 3;
     public boolean move() {
        System.out.println("Checkers move " + moves);
        return ++moves != MOVES;
     }
}

class CheckersFactory implements GameFactory {
    public Game getGame() { return new Checkers(); }
}

class Chess implements Game {
    private int moves = 0;
    private static final int MOVES = 4;
    public boolean move() {
       print("Chess move " + moves);
       return ++moves != MOVES;
    }
}

class ChessFactory implements GameFactory {
    public Game getGame() { return new Chess(); }
}
```

(3) And the client code

```
public class Games {
    public static void playGame(GameFatory factory) {
        Game s = factory.getGame();
        while (s.move());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        playGame(new CheckersFactory());
        playGame(new ChessFactory());
    }
}
```

So as for the client code, why do we bother to pass the `GameFactory` to the function of `playGame`?

Can we just set `Game` as the argument as follows:

```
public class Games {
    public static void playGame(Game game) {
        while (game.move());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        playGame(new Checkers());
        playGame(new Chess());
    }
}
```

So that there is no need for us to create a `GameFactory` to just get the `Game`

So I wonder what is the advantage of the Factory Method?

Comment: Does the book not explain the advantage of using a factory in this case?

Comment: What if you had to write a method that plays ten chess games in a row? If playGame takes a Game as argument how can the method be sure that the game hasn't be started by someone else before?

Comment: FWIW, `getGame` is a terrible name for the factory method here, as it obscures the true purpose of the method. If you renamed `getGame` to `startGame` it would make the example much clearer.

Comment: @NickL 
It says `If the Games class represents a complex piece of code, this approach allows you to reuse that code with different types of games.`

Comment: @JBNizet I am quite sure what do you mean. Do you mean it is related to the implementation of the Game?

Comment: @DanielPryden Could you please explain it in more detail?

Comment: No. I means what i wrote. By passing the Gamefactory, the method can loop 10 times and start 10 different games. If you passed games, you would have to create 10 games by yourself.

Comment: But different games have their own factory. In your case, you need to create 10 GameFactory for each game and pass 10 GameFactory to the Games. @JBNizet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Factory pattern exists to provide an object-oriented version of a functional programming idiom: providing a functor that generates values. Most often you see Factory combined with something like the Strategy pattern, where you have an interface that represents a way of doing something, and multiple concrete implementations of that interface that represent different ways to do that thing. The value of a Factory is that it abstracts the *creation* of a strategy.

In practice, I find this useful in two situations:

1. When client code needs to choose a strategy, but library code needs to control when and how often that strategy is used. This matches your Game example: a `GameFactory` represents a *kind* of game (chess, checkers, etc.), while a `Game` instance represents a particular game. If you were writing a class that played a tournament of matches between different players, you would need to construct it with a GameFactory to tell it what kind of game to play, but the Tournament itself would determine how many games to start and how to manipulate each game. Tournament can't just do `new Chess()` or `new Checkers()` because the goal is to make the Tournament class independent of the kind of game, so that it's reusable.
2. Factory is also useful when creating a value is complex and you want essentially do partial application of the constructor. This approach often works well together with the Dependency Injection pattern. For example, consider that you now add a third kind of game, `Poker`. A `Poker` game needs a random-number generator so that it knows how to shuffle the cards. How do you fit that into your existing GameFactory/Game/Tournament structure? The `PokerFactory` object would take the random number generator as an argument, and it would be responsible for passing along the random number generator to any `PokerGame` objects it creates. A class that uses the GameFactory/Game API, like Tournament, wouldn't need to know that some games need a random number generator and some don't; that knowledge would be abstracted away.

Taking a step back: like most OO design patterns, the whole purpose of the Factory pattern is to *reduce coupling* and *increase cohesion*. You don't want your Tournament class to be *coupled* to any particular game; decoupling the code makes it possible for the different parts of your program to change independently of each other.

Taking an even farther step back: much of the knowledge and best practice around software engineering comes from *large* software projects, with so many lines of code that no human can remember everything that's going on everywhere, and with so many people working on the project that coordinating work between different parts of the program becomes one of the most important problems to solve. So many design patterns exist because they define "seams" between different parts of the programs to compartmentalize the concepts you need to hold in your head at one time. This allows two or more programmers to work on the different compartments at the same time, and makes it easier for you to ensure that each compartment is correct.

In the kind of "toy" programs you write when learning a programming language or when studying programming for the first time, these tactics to compartmentalize a program may seem redundant or simply confusing. And indeed, if you apply these kinds of patterns unnecessarily then they actually make things worse, not better. But these techniques are "tools" to have in your toolbelt when you approach a large body of code: both so that you can better understand how the existing code is compartmentalized and so that you can compartmentalize the code you write.

TL;DR: "Everything should be made as simple as possible, but no simpler."

Answer (score 0):

Question is too broad for that site, since it is about theory and not about problem to solve.

But in short: it is a pattern and you are free to use another ones.

Main purpose of interface is to have different classes with different implementations of the same methods. So, factory gives an ability to create objects in different ways instead of deal with more complex constructors. As example you need different code to construct object withe the same arguments, perhaps based on OS or app server where code runs. So, how you will do it? Then there is a way to provide factory for Linux, another for Windows and so on.

You do not need to have both everywhere...

Another advantage is about memory management and garbage collector. By using **new** inside method there is a good possibility to end up with orphaned instance which will be cleaned only by full GC which is very expensive. With factory as Singleton it will never happen,

BTW: in your simple example neither interface nor factory required.

Again there are many patterns to choose from to fit actual needs.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.
As for that example 
`As example you need different code to construct object withe the same arguments, perhaps based on OS or app server where code runs. So, how you will do it? Then there is a way to provide factory for Linux, another for Windows and so on.`
Could you please make it more explicit? I still don't quite understand why there is a need to provide factory for Linux rather than just use the Linux Interface.

Comment: Maybe it is not a good example i typed from phone. All is about separate API from implementation. You may look at Java Servlet API (it is about interfaces) or javax.xml.soap (actually it has abstract factories too)... then every implementor, let say Weblogic, WebSphere ... and so on implement them as they want to... This for what Interfaces and Factories stand for. Developer uses interfaces/factories and does not care where it will run. Still,  Factory pattern is better than just using **new**. BTW if it is only about one time running program from **main** class Factory is not neccessary.